# Can another program force Windows to update itself even though updates are paused?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

This is what happened:

Yesterday I paused the updates for 7 days in the settings because I needed to quickly shut down the computer and there was update on the line.

Today I installed IntelliJ IDEA Community and after finishing the installer it asked me to reboot the computer. But instead of quick restart that I expected, it took 15 minutes to boot up again.

It was showing the usual stuff when updating ... 4 % .... 30 % ... wait until Windows is ready.

After booting up, I looked into the settings and updates were still paused. So I unpaused them to check if the update I delayed yesterday was still uninstalled and surprisingly it was installed.

I checked for updates and it says: You're up to date.

So what actually happened?
Could IDEA force the update?
What can I do to prevent this and be in full control over the updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has released lately one or more urgent updates.
Such updates are called "out-of-band" and do not respect any pause parameter,
which apparently is what happened to you.

From  [Windows 10 update servicing cadence](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/Windows-10-update-servicing-cadence/ba-p/222376):

> An **out-of-band release** is any update that does not follow the standard release schedule. These are reserved for situations where devices must be updated immediately either to fix security vulnerabilities or to solve a quality issues impacting many devices.

IntelliJ IDEA Community didn't force the update : It was already downloaded
and ready, waiting for the next reboot.